# Compute $\sum_{x\in\mathcal{N}}\sum_{y\in\mathcal{N}}\frac{1}{x+y+1}$

Tags: summation, roots-of-unity

> Let $n$ be a natural number with $3\nmid n$. Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the set of all $n$-th roots of unity. Then calculate $$\sum_{x\in\mathcal{I}}\sum_{y\in\mathcal{I}}\frac{1}{x+y+1}$$

I tried to simplify the form of the problem by expressing the roots through the primitive root (say $y_0$) as follows $$\sum_{j\in(\overline{0,n-1})}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{y_0^j+y_0^k+1}=\sum_{j\in(\overline{0,n-1})}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{y_0^j+y_0^k+y_0^n}$$ and was going to come down to further workable form, by factoring every time the term $y_0^{min(k,j,n)}$ in the denominator. But some tests vaguely show that this process may last periodically with no any useful result...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Clear the denominator and apply [Vieta's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) as $x_i,y_i$ are the roots of $x^n-1$, $y^n-1$, but seems a long way to go

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin what do you mean by "Clearing the denominator"?

Comment: I mean find the common denominator $\prod\limits_{0\le i<n\\0\le j<n} (x_i+y_j+1)$, don't know the English term right. Like making from $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}\quad\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$

Comment: We can restate your question in terms of matrices: Let $A$ be the $n\times n$-matrix whose $\left(i,j\right)$-th entry is $1$ if $j \equiv i+1 \mod n$ and $0$ otherwise. Then, your double sum is the trace of $\left(I_n \otimes I_n + A \otimes I_n + I_n \otimes A\right)^{-1}$. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: Empirically, the answer seems to be $n^2/3$, by the way.

Comment: I don't have a proof, just a guess.

Comment: @darijgrinberg But you said that the answer seems to $n^2/3$ :)

Comment: Here is a different approach. Instead of computing your sum, let us compute the rational function $F\left(t\right) = \sum\limits_{x \in \mathcal{N}} \sum\limits_{y \in \mathcal{N}} \dfrac{1}{1-\left(x+y\right)t}$, and then evaluate the result at $t=-1$. We can expand $F\left(t\right)$ into a formal power series at $t=0$, obtaining $F\left(t\right) = n^2 \sum\limits_{i \geq 0} \sum\limits_{j \geq 0} \dbinom{ni+nj}{ni} t^{ni+nj}$ (using standard techniques: geometric series and roots-of-unity filter). I suspect this sum should be recognizable.

Comment: Okay, $F\left(t\right)$ doesn't look particularly nice for $n=7$, so this is probably not the right track.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Would you care to post an answer?

Comment: Nooooooooo, I can't do that with bare hands. Is there some software I can use?)

Comment: More general conjecture: If $n$ and $k$ are positive integers, then $\sum\limits_{\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right) \in \mathcal{N}^k} \dfrac{1}{1+x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k} = \dfrac{n^k}{k+1}$ assuming that all denominators on the left hand side are nonzero. This is easy to prove for $k = 1$.

Comment: ([Some Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFj7EOgjAURfd-xU1cWjRiB0cnEnYGJ-OAUPGF0kfaooGvt6iJ07u59-Qk71yUOOHs6Gl8qG0xN5YjD9SUZGwrq0oJlwCtRZ_OUdw9D6BofGS2ATSM7CNGz-3URLGsrqLcd8ZJp8Qy8iuk6rJkGeHOHgRy8LXrTNqvX2AVWwpR_izy0-7gzWjqeOqVEqszTIPUyCH1do2k1N_49ai0uizrsUF48GRbdOkt6Fz2W62Q4JaeFIgdbjMOb0UhUIw=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) to check the conjecture in small cases.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice for any $z \in \mathcal{N}$, the map $\mathcal{N} \ni x \mapsto xz\in \mathcal{N}$ is a permutation over $\mathcal{N}$. We have

$$\sum_{x,y \in \mathcal{N}} \frac{1}{x + y + 1}
= \sum_{x,y \in \mathcal{N}} \frac{z}{zx + zy + z}
= \sum_{x,y \in \mathcal{N}} \frac{z}{x + y +z }
$$
Take average over $z$, we obtain

$$\sum_{x,y \in \mathcal{N}} \frac{1}{x + y + 1}
= \frac1n \sum_{x,y,z\in\mathcal{N}} \frac{z}{x+y+z}$$
By symmetry among $x,y,z$, this leads to

$$\sum_{x,y \in \mathcal{N}} \frac{1}{x + y + 1}
= \frac1{3n}\sum_{x,y,z\in\mathcal{N}}\frac{x + y + z}{x + y + z} = \frac1{3n} n^3 = \frac{n^2}{3}$$

By a similar argument, it is trivial to show

$$\mathcal{I}_k \stackrel{def}{=}\sum_{x_1,\ldots,x_k \in \mathcal{N}}\frac{1}{1+ \sum_{j=1}^k x_j}
= \sum_{x_1,\ldots,x_k \in \mathcal{N}}\frac{z}{z + \sum_{j=1}^k x_j}, \forall z \in \mathcal{N}
$$

As long as we are working with a $n$ where $\sum_{j=1}^k x_j = -1$ doesn't have a solution in $\mathcal{N}^k$, this leads to

$$\mathcal{I}_k
= \frac{1}{(k+1)n}\sum_{z,x_1,\ldots,x_k \in \mathcal{N}}\frac{z + \sum_{j=1}^k x_j}{z+ \sum_{j=1}^k x_j}
= \frac{1}{(k+1)n} n^{k+1} = \frac{n^k}{k+1}$$

Comment: Wow!!! This argument also proves my generalization in the comments.

Comment: @darijgrinberg yup, that's the magic of go to sleep, wake up and think of the problem during shower.